# Error running mongoose update code ( router.patch() )

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm getting an error running router.patch() code to update a product on a cloud-based mongoose database.  I'm using Postman to simulate the update.  Postman's error is showing, "req.body[Symbol.iterator] is not a function."  Here is the relevant code:

Products.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Product = require('../models/product');


    router.patch('/:productId', (req, res, next) => {
        const id = req.params.productId;
        // don't want to update both fields if not needed
        const updateOps = {};
        // loop through all the operations of the request body
        for (const ops of req.body) {
            updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
        }
        Product.update({_id: id}, { $set: updateOps })// $set is a mongoose object
            .exec()
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                res.status(200).json(result);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: err
                });
            });
            {req.body.newName, price, req.body.newPrice} ;
            res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Updated product',
        });
    });


module.exports = router
```

Product.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    price: Number
});
// export the schema into the Mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  :-)

Comment: `for (const ops of req.body) {
            updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
        }` this is your issue, I think.

Comment: What should I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, this part is likely your problem:

```
for (const ops of req.body) {
  updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
}
```

Since `req.body` is an Object, I think you want:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(req.body)){
  updateOps[key.propName] = value;
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to translate your answer into my script. Do I replace 'Object' with req.body?  Do I use the terms [key, value] or do I replace them with something specific to my code?

Comment: Ok, I'll try that in a little bit.